# How to do transitional for loop in Mustache template?

Tags: php, templates, loops, mustache

Just started using Mustache template in PHP. I've read Manual, but looks like there's no tranditional loop in Mustache.

How do I simulate the following loop in Mustache?

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that by assigning an array with the values 0 to 9. See http://php.net/range how to create such an array easily.

In mustache, think more in terms of *foreach*  than *for*  or *while*.

Answer (score 0):

Mustache only uses `<tags>`, so lets assume $MustacheData is the variable passed to your template, and lets wrap $i in ul,li elements.  You will need to define all data used in your template before your template renders.

PHP

```
$MustacheData = array(

    'i' = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)    
);
```

Mustache

```
<ul>
    <il>{{i}}</li>
</ul>
```

Mustache Advanced

The first template will render one `<li>` even if `$i` is not defined in your data, so you can also write the template like this:

```
<ul>
    {{#i}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/i}}
<ul>
```